# How do I stop an NSView subview being resized with Auto Layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, autolayout

I am having a problem with the new Auto Layout functionality.
I add an NSView called tableView as a subview of workingBox.  workingBox also contains some other subviews that were added with Interface Builder

```
[self.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
[workingBox addSubview:tableView];
```

My problem is that if any of the other subviews touch tableView then they will get resized in the animation.  The subviews that are not near where tableView is being added remain the correct size. I have already tried setting NSViewNotSizable resizeMask on the subviews that are getting resized but it does not work.  The only thing that works is moving the subview upwards (into the wrong position.

---

EDIT: I have added a constraint in code:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(divider);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[divider(==1)]"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary];
[workingBox addConstraints:constraints];
```

This keeps the NSView at 1px height but if I lock it to the top it prevents the superview growing

Comment: Can you upload an image with the phenomenon you describe and add more relevant code?

Comment: I think the key to this is based on this: [Suppose you drag a text field out of the library, snap it into the bottom left corner of a window, then drag-resize the right edge until it snaps into the bottom right corner. Nothing further is needed to specify that when the window is resized the text field should stretch horizontally](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html)  I am guessing I need to add a constraint with code to override one that is being added based on the positioning of the NSView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make this work by adding a constraint in code.  However in Interface Builder I could see that there was a constraint for the NSView in question that was named 'Bottom Alignment'. I changed this to a priority of 1 in the inspector and it stopped the NSView getting stretched down when the window expanded.  I think this auto added constraint that I mentioned in my comment above had been the problem all along.

Comment: Because my layout was pretty much fixed I decided to ditch Auto Layout in the end as it was just causing too many complications. I went back to basics and laid everything out in the traditional manner and all has been good.